# How can I calculate Azure Synapse pipeline costs

Tags: azure-synapse

I would like to calculate the cost of running a Azure Synapse pipeline (a Spark notebook).

I can see the cost for my region is $0.138 per vCore-hour:-

[image]

and the execution hours were 0.1167:-

[image]

So is the total cost $0.138 * 0.1167?

Are execution hours are actually execution ***vCore***-hours?

Is anyone able to confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the understanding is correct.

[image]

> **Note:** You pay for the Data Flow cluster execution and debugging time per vCore-hour. The minimum cluster size to run a Data Flow is 8
> vCores. Execution and debugging charges are prorated by the minute and
> rounded up.

Hence, As mentioned in above you will be paying for the Data Flow Cluster execution and debugging time per vCore-hour, which is the Integration hours along with the time take per vCore hour.

Comment: This is only the pipeline cost The question refers to running a spark notebook which starts a separate spark cluster to run the notebook. The cost will depend on the number of executors available in the spark cluster and if dynamic allocation of executors is enabled.